# Creating full-calendar-react :: error dateProfileGenerator is undefined

Tags: reactjs, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Trying to make Full-Calendar component for reactjs, and fill it up with events retrieved from firestore database (Retrieving the events when changing the month).
But no matter what i do, i receive the error about `dateProfileGenerator`, so the code below is the code that i use just i deleted the part where i retrieve from the db, and still does not work.

```
import React from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

Receiving this error:

> TypeError: dateProfileGenerator is undefined

Here is the code i am trying to run.

```
const DemoCalendar = () => {
    
return (
    <FullCalendar
      headerToolbar={{
        left: 'prev, next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek, timeGridDay, listMonth'
      }}
      initialDate={new Date()}
      navLinks="true"
      businessHours="true"
      editable="false"
      selectable="true"
      events={[
        {
          title: 'Business',
          start: '2021-05-05T10:00:00',
          end: '2021-05-06T10:30:00',
          constraint: 'businessHours',
          color: '#257e4a'
        },
        {
          groupId: 'available',
          start: '2021-05-06T10:00:00',
          end: '2021-05-06T10:30:00',
          display: 'background'
        }
      ]}
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      initialView="dayGridMonth"
    />
  );
};
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error using React. I still don't know what's wrong, but it works after I moved my main code to the React project example here:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/react
I then installed @fullcalendar/list additionally, which is not included in the original example.

My guess is I might have mistyped something or I didn't not install @fullcalendar/list correctly. For your case I think you may have forgotten to enter this line of code

```
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'
```

If not, you can try to modify the React example project. Maybe moving your code to a new project also works. Reinstalling the whole node_modules doesn't help.

Update: Changing the folder name helps when I encountered another error today.